# How to add emojis to text in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, emoji

How can I make emojis appear in a text box in Inkscape?

I'm running Inkscape v1.0.2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15) on Debian 11 (bullseye). I cannot get emojis to appear in an SVG that I'm creating in Inkscape. For example:

1. I open Inkscape.
2. I create a new document.
3. I create a text box.
4. I type a string with some emojis between two pipes “emojis:||” in OpenSans font.
5. The emojis are not visible:

[image]

Curiously, the emojis appear in the “preview” of the `Font` and `Text` tabs of the `Text and Font` window, but they do *not* appear on the main/edit window itself.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the emojis to appear in Inkscape?

Comment: See also https://inkscape.org/forums/questions/calling-all-users-emojissymbols-in-inkscape/?c=45212#c45212

Comment: This is a bug that can be partially resolved by removing the "Noto Color Emoji" font with `sudo apt-get purge fonts-noto-color-emoji` https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/570

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Inkscape doesn't support display of multi colour emojis. Although you should still be able see the emojis, they will display as monochrome, but when exporting as SVG, they should display in colour in a browser. Make sure you have the most recent Inkscape - (currently 1.2.1)

Example: What I see in Inskcape 1.2.1

[image]

Here's [the SVG file](https://svgshare.com/i/jmj.svg) which you can see is colour when displayed in a browser, assuming the font is installed locally. This example is the SVG shown in Firefox

[image]

Comment: If the font isn't installed locally, standard font substitution seems to apply to your web share - I got this, distinctly Apple. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaAdC.png

Comment: @Tetsujin - yeah, distinctly Apple!

Comment: @BillyKerr "What I see in Inskcape 1.2.1" can you please also add the OS/flavour and version?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield - sorry, this is Windows 10, Inkscape 1.2.1, SVG viewed in Firefox 103.0.1 - the font is the default sans-serif in Inkscape, and isn't specified in the SVG.  The SVG was exported from Inkscape using "Plain SVG".